# Nodejs fluentd logger

Tags: node.js, logging, fluentd

I am using the nodejs - fluentd logger (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-node) and I use the following configuration as specified in this link.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 24224,
  timeout: 3.0,
  requireAckResponse: false // Add this option to wait response from Fluentd certainly
};
var fluentTransport = require('fluent-logger').support.winstonTransport();
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [new fluentTransport('mytag', config), new (winston.transports.Console)()]
});
```

**requireAckResponse** - I use this flag and it shows that it won't wait for the fluentd response but will it wait till the log data is written to the fluentd log file?

1) When exactly the response will be returned from fluentd for log write? 
2) What are the advantages and dis-advantages of using this ?

Thanks,
Harry